# Inheritance models from Django 1.8.2 to Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the task of convert the project from django version 1.8.2 to version 1.11. Faced a problem with which I can not cope. That model of tables, which worked excellently in 1.8.2, stopped working in version 1.11, and falls out with an error:

```
core.CarModel.manufacture: (models.E006) The field 'manufacture' clashes with the field 'manufacture' from model 'core.page'.
```

Apparently this is due to the inheritance of models, since the project is old I can not fundamentally change the scheme of tables, please tell me how to get out of this situation.
Thank you in advance for your help.

I have reproduced the scheme of models, which works fine on 1.8.2 and stops working on 1.11:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class InheritanceCastModel(models.Model):

    real_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.real_type = self._get_real_type()
        super(InheritanceCastModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_real_type(self):
        return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))

    def cast(self):
        return self.real_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Page(InheritanceCastModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=u'Title', blank=True)


class Manufacture(Page):
    ru_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=u'RU Title')


class CarModel(Page):
     # here problem:         
    manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufacture, verbose_name=u'Manufacture')
    ru_title = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name=u'RU Title')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the Page model is inherited by the Manufacture model, django creates a surrogate field "manufacture" for Page objects, but this name is used in the CarModel model, which results in a conflict. In django version 1.8, the field was called "manufacture_ptr", so there was no conflict. In the version of django 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, the field is called as "manufacture".

The solution is to change the field name in the CarModel model from "manufacture" to another.